# jQuery Toggle button not clickable after first click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

The menu expands and contracts when I click on a button.
The button toggles the "active" class when I click it as expected with only the code required for that action.
However, when I add the code to make the the menu contract when clicking elsewhere on the page, it only contracts when clicking everything EXCEPT for the button.
The button is no longer clickable and the menu remains expanded until I click on a link or on the body of the page.

EDIT: As I was typing this out on a jsfiddle, I got an error on that console that I don't see in my dev tools:
**Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined**
The reason why I am not using the "$"symbol that I see everyone using, and I am writting out "jQuery" in front of everything is because that's the only way I could make DIVI (the wordpress builder) compile the code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    
    jQuery('.nav__button').click(function(){

        jQuery(this).toggleClass('button--active');
        jQuery('.nav__row').toggleClass('nav__row--active');

    });
}); 
    
jQuery(document).mouseup(e => {

   if (!jQuery('nav__container').is(e.target)
   && jQuery('nav__container').has(e.target).length === 0) {

     jQuery('.nav__row').removeClass('nav__row--active');
     jQuery('.nav__button').removeClass('button--active');
  }
 });
```

And If I add this line of code, I break the code all together.

```
jQuery('.nav__button').is(e.target) ||
```

This line is added to the second function, to say that "If I click on the button OR elsewhere" [contract the menu]

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    
    jQuery('.nav__button').click(function(){

        jQuery(this).toggleClass('button--active');
        jQuery('.nav__row').toggleClass('nav__row--active');

    });
}); 
    
jQuery(document).mouseup(e => {

   if (!jQuery('nav__container').is(e.target)
   && jQuery('nav__container').has(e.target).length === 0) {

     jQuery('.nav__row').removeClass('nav__row--active');
     jQuery('.nav__button').removeClass('button--active');
  }
 });
```

```css
.nav__row {
  transition: .3s;
  overflow: visible !important;
}

.nav__container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  height: 30px;
}

.nav__container img {
  height: 14px;
  margin-top: auto;
}

.nav__link-panel {
  position: absolute;
  width: 175px;
  height: 220px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: right;
  transform: translatex(-100%);
  background-color: #dcf5ee;
  padding-top: 75px !important;
  padding-right: 25px !important;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.nav__row.nav__row--active {
  transition: .3s;
  transform: translatex(70%);
}

/*Hamburger animation*/
.nav__button {
  width: 24px;
  height: 6px;
  position: relative;
  background: transparent;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
}

.nav__button span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: .25s ease-in-out;
}

.nav__button span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0px;
  transform-origin: left center;
}

.nav__button span:nth-child(2) {
  top: 8px;
  width: 80%;
  transform-origin: left center;
}

.nav__button span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 16px;
  transform-origin: left center;
}

.nav__button.button--active span:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: 0px;
  left: 8px;
}

.nav__button.button--active span:nth-child(2) {
  width: 0%;
  opacity: 0;
}

.nav__button.button--active span:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  top: 17px;
  left: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav__container">
    <div class="nav__menu">
         <button class="nav__button">
             <span></span>
             <span></span>
             <span></span>
          </button>
          <ul class="nav__link-panel" >
             <li><a> Contact </a></li>
          </ul>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Could you please add the relevant HTML and CSS to the question so we can see a working example of the issue

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan absolutely. Let me try to figure out how to share a jfiddle

Comment: You can add codes to SO snippet.

Comment: @ikhvjs stackoverflow just suggested that edit. I didn't know how to do it, but now there is one and I hope it helps. 
As you can see, the "X" only closes and becomes a burger when you click outside of the window. If you click the X to close the menu, nothing happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The toggles in each of your handlers are competing with each other: events from one will bubble up to the other causing them to both fire simultaneously, toggling the nav right back to its initial state.  Here I changed the 'body' handler to only remove the 'active' classes; and added a stopPropagation to the nav click handler so it doesn't bubble up and also trigger the body handler.

(I also added a bit of CSS to cause `body` to fill the viewport.)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){        
    jQuery('.nav__button, .nav__container').click(function(e){
        jQuery('.nav__button').toggleClass('button--active');
        jQuery('.nav__row').toggleClass('nav__row--active');
        e.stopPropagation() // prevents the event from also triggering the 'body' handler below
    });

    // Remove (don't toggle) 'active' when clicking outside the nav:
    jQuery('body').click(function(e){
        jQuery('.nav__button').removeClass('button--active');
        jQuery('.nav__row').removeClass('nav__row--active');
        e.stopPropagation()
    });
});
```

```css
body {height: 100vh}
.nav__row {
  transition: .3s;
  overflow: visible !important;
}

.nav__container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  height: 30px;
}

.nav__container img {
  height: 14px;
  margin-top: auto;
}

.nav__link-panel {
  position: absolute;
  width: 175px;
  height: 220px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: right;
  transform: translatex(-100%);
  background-color: #dcf5ee;
  padding-top: 75px !important;
  padding-right: 25px !important;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.nav__row.nav__row--active {
  transition: .3s;
  transform: translatex(70%);
}

/*Hamburger animation*/
.nav__button {
  width: 24px;
  height: 6px;
  position: relative;
  background: transparent;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
}

.nav__button span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: .25s ease-in-out;
}

.nav__button span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0px;
  transform-origin: left center;
}

.nav__button span:nth-child(2) {
  top: 8px;
  width: 80%;
  transform-origin: left center;
}

.nav__button span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 16px;
  transform-origin: left center;
}

.nav__button.button--active span:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: 0px;
  left: 8px;
}

.nav__button.button--active span:nth-child(2) {
  width: 0%;
  opacity: 0;
}

.nav__button.button--active span:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  top: 17px;
  left: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav__container">
    <div class="nav__menu">
         <button class="nav__button">
             <span></span>
             <span></span>
             <span></span>
          </button>
          <ul class="nav__link-panel" >
             <li><a> Contact </a></li>
          </ul>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I realized after this answer was accepted that I missed the "clicking outside the navbar closes it" part of the situation.  Have rewritten the answer to include that.